# error could not find class file for 'com.myproject.myactivity'

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I am trying to make a simple Android NDK app. So I have some issue I cant get it done.

I have a manual that says what I have to do:
First part:

1)create a new project using Eclipse

2)run it on my device

Second part:

1)next step I have to make .h library using the javah.exe

2)open file MyActivity.java and declare a method

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public native String getMyData();
```

3)load a library that has a method

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("mylib");
    }
```

4)call a method after creating a copy of class Activity

```
...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTitle(getMyData());
    }
}
```

5)than I have to create a jni folder in my project`s main folder

6) in the jni folder create a file Android.mk and put these lines in it

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE   := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_myproject_MyActivity.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Third part:

7)Eclipse =>Run => External Tools => External Tools Configurations.. and make next declarations:

```
Name: MyProject javah
Location: ${env_var:JAVA_HOME}\bin\javah.exe
Working directory: ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/bin}
Arguments: -d ${workspace_loc:/MyProject/jni} com.myproject.MyActivity
```

8) Press apply and run.

---

After all I have an error msg:

```
error could not find class file for 'com.myproject.myactivity'
```

---

I have been searching a lot of solutions and none of those were helpful.

Please help, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Be sure to declare it in the Manifest.

Comment: @zgulser please explain what exactly I have to declare in Manifest?

Comment: Come onn! Just google it.